# Tomcat: Java Webservice deployment not working - Status 404

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans

Hi all, I was using payara before, but wanted to change to Tomcat 9 now. 
My problem is, that I am not able to deploy and use my java webservice as I hoped.
 I programmed a very easy web service in Netbeans and created the .war file. In payara I just deployed it and could access the rest endpoints - for instance domain.com/Hello/v1/test. 
 
In tomcat I deployed the war file as well, but I am not able to access anything. I always receive a 404 the whole time. 
 I just can access the domain.com/Hello page where the index.html is located. 
I checked the folder in webapps and its pretty empty. I think this is where the error is: 
I have the following structure:

```
Hello 
 -index.html 
 - WEB-INF
      -lib 
     -java-json.jar 
   -classes 
      -com 
         -domain 
           -hello 
              -test.class
              -auth.class 
               -dbconnection.class
```

I hope anyone can help me. I am completely new to tomcat and with payara it was very easy to just create the java classes, endpoints and deploy the war file

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just relaxed a little bit and realized how stupid I was. I needed to update the main path I was using in my AppConfig class. I will close this, but not delete it. Maybe someone will look for this mistake someday.